# Do bosses or boss encounters respawn?

Tags: borderlands-2

Is it possible to return to a point of a boss fight or encounter and redo the fight after you've completed the associated quests? Would certainly make farming for good items much easier.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not only do most bosses respawn, even the final boss respawns.

However, the boss listed in the "Midgame spoiler" section below is replaced by a similar, new boss. And the second-to-last boss is the only other boss that doesn't respawn. Every other boss respawns 100% of the time.

Midgame spoiler:

> Bloodwing does not respawn, but Son of Mothrakk spawns in her place, the fight is similar but he doesn't change elements and is generally much easier. Presumably he drops similar items.

Final battle spoiler:

> Handsome Jack does not respawn, but the Warrior does. Seems you have one chance per playthrough to get Jack's Mask for this reason. You also won't get the generic loot that Jack would have dropped if you fight Warrior again, but Warrior drops plenty on his own If you get two Jack's Masks, keep one for a friend.

Any boss that drops unique loot respawns — except for the final battle (see the spoiler part above), but that boss can only possibly drop one unique item anyway: a specific skin customization.

Comment: I need to see if Wilhelm or the BNK3R respawn

Comment: they do, I've tried it.

Comment: re: # of waves, having replayed {spoiler} many times (win collect exit continue), I am certain that {spoiler} {spoilers} 3 waves always.

Comment: @horatio edited that part out. I must have been mistaken, I've noticed that boss drops loot in the same way even after the story event

Answer (score 5):

**Yes they do**. I do a morning stroll through Boom Bewm daily just cause i love the splash screen >w<

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Every time you leave and reenter an area (a loading screen) all mobs respawn. There may be a few exceptions to that rule though.

Comment: Are you sure? Because i think once a boss is killed he will stay dead.

Comment: All the bosses I have encountered so far have respawned.

Comment: @Lyrion They respawn, just takes some time.

Comment: Bloodwing did not respawn for me but was replaced by the Son of Mothrakk

Comment: -1: This is definitely not true on the PC version.  If you clear an area and fast travel away/back it will still be cleared.  Some time later the mobs will spawn again (or if you exit the game).

Comment: Everything is on a respawn timer. Enemies respawn either when their timer expires OR they are pushed out of the respawn list by newer entries.

Answer (score 0):

Enemies respawn each day in-game. Clear out an area in the daytime, and they will respawn the next morning. Alternatively, you can clear an area, then quit and reload to make things go faster if you are looking to farm an area.

Comment: Welcome to ArqadeSE. Are you sure it takes so long to respawn? I'm pretty sure when I played that enemies spawn back faster. You should back your answer (and each future answer on SE sites) with evidence such as official sources (hopefully with links to them if available) and/or personal experience.