# How can I farm Jimbo Hodunk?

Tags: borderlands-2

Jimbo Hodunk drops a rare SMG I want, the Slagga. I don't recall ever fighting him, and if I did I don't remember where.

How do I find Jimbo Hodunk? Does he respawn? Do I have to chose to fight against the Hodunks in that questline to fight him or does it matter?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After you complete the all the side quests linked with Clan War: Zafords vs Hodunks and choose to go with the Zafords and you kill all the Hodunks, anytime you go back to the dust and go to the exit where Lynchwood is the Hodunks will respawn and you can farm that way. Good Luck getting the SMG.

(The exit to Lynchwood from The Dust is a train station)

Comment: Yep, I've been farming him by going to the entrance of Lynchwood from Dust. The Hodunks will be standing on the right-hand platform facing Lynchwood, should be very easy to spot.

Answer (score 4):

Right, I've not come up against Hodunk myself, so I'll be using the Wiki for the first part. The Hodunks are at the Hodunk Speedway, in The Dust.

As far as I've seen, all bosses respawn, even if they're bosses for a side quest (examples: the Splinter Group, Boll). [Verification from elsewhere on Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85570/do-boss-or-boss-encounters-respawn). When they respawn, all of their little friends respawn. So, if there were a bunch of people between you and him, or that hung around him, you'll have to fight them as well (examples: Boom Bewm's Psychos, Flynt's Burning Psychos, Boll's pet Skags).

... Wow, I managed to talk about bosses without spoilers. Awesome.

EDIT: As mentioned in that link to elsewhere on this site, the bosses will only respawn once you complete the mission involving them (namely, get mission, kill boss, turn in mission). So, you can't farm Jimbo until you've completed the mission to kill him at least once.

Comment: Ahah, I remember where he must have spawned then. I remember the speedway fight, I'll confirm this tonight

Comment: The Hodunks are initially in the Speedway area, but you can't fight  their clan leader at this point in the quest line. See Robert Palmer's answer.

Comment: Ah. As I said, I was relying on the Wiki for location. It doesn't mention that they move. Apologies for the incorrect information with regards to location.