# Are all Bosses farmable?

Tags: borderlands-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do bosses or boss encounters respawn?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85570/do-bosses-or-boss-encounters-respawn)

I've been trying to farm Wilhelm, but he doesn't appear after beating him initially. Do I have to be in Vault Hunter mode to farm him, or is this just a bug for me?

Comment: And yeah, Wilhem respawns, but remember to leave the game before trying to find him again. You have to complete the mission for the boss for them to show up again too, if you haven't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bosses do respawn, so yes. The quickest way to make this happen is to save your game, quit to menu and continue from where you left off. Certain maps, such as the Vault and Terramorphous' lair even spawn you right inside the map where you left off; this might also be the case for End of the Line.

I've been visiting End of the Line on playthrough 1 after beating the story mission related to it and Wilhelm was there waiting to kill me - he definitively does respawn.

Comment: Oh./. maybe I had to quit and come back. I just re-entered the map :\ Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've killed Wilhelm multiple times. The first time I was alone, then I joined a group game and the group happened to be playing that mission.

Comment: I don't think you can rely on random groups to farm a boss. Farming entails either single player or a group with the specific goal of killing a particular boss in the game.