# How can we restart a game?

Tags: borderlands

I have done playthrough 2 completely. 
My question is: How can we start over with our upgraded characters?

Is there any reset but keep your character option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to reset all quest progress without save file tampering (and to my knowledge there aren't useful save file editors for that yet). You can however reset *badass challenge* progress after receiving something like 80% of the challenges.

Pretty much the best option you can have is to join the game of a host who hasn't completed the game and you can run through the missions again. You won't receive any rewards for missions you've already completed though. It's also not something that's easy to set up spontaneously.

Comment: So I can never defeat the big boss again on playtrought 2.5 while on solo ?

Comment: I've been told that sometimes it gives good drops, but I don't seem to find a way to kill the boss again. :(

Comment: @mem bosses respawn

Comment: @BenBrocka I think they are talking about the big end game boss.

Comment: @Ids he respawns too: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85570/do-bosses-or-boss-encounters-respawn/85864#85864

Comment: Does he in borderlands 1?

Comment: This question is about borderlands 1, which does have good save-file editors...